# Regex PHP - dont match specific string followed by numeric

Tags: php, regex

Im looping over a large number of files in a directory, and want to extract all the numeric values in a filename where it starts `lin64exe` , for instance, `lin64exe005458002.17` would match `005458002.17`. I have this part sorted, but in the directory there are other files, such as `part005458` and others. How can I make it so I only get the numeric (and . ) after `lin64exe` ?

This is what I have so far:

```
[^lin64exe][^OTHERTHINGSHERE$][0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with look around as well

```
(?<=^lin64exe)\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aM7dI4/7)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    ^                        the beginning of the string
    lin64exe                 'lin64exe'
  )                        end of look-behind

  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (most possible))
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional):
    \.                       '.'
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (most possible))
  )?                       end of \1

  $                        the end of the string
```

**Note:** use `i` for ignore case

sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=^lin64exe)\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$/i";
$str = "lin64exe005458002.17\nlin64exe005458002\npart005458";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I changed it slightly to `(?<=^lin64exe)\d+(.+\d+)?$` to match any `.`s but this worked. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regex to match the number with decimal point which was just after to `lin64exe` is,

```
^lin64exe\K\d+\.\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aM7dI4/2)

```
<?php
$mystring = "lin64exe005458002.17";
$regex = '~^lin64exe\K\d+\.\d+$~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 005458002.17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and use captured group #1 for your number:

```
^lin64exe\D*([\d.]+)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD2aE3/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/^lin64exe\D*([\d.]+)$/i'; 
$str = "lin64exe005458002.17\npart005458"; 

if ( preg_match($re, $str, $m) )
    var_dump ($m[1]);
```